# re rendering is making the file chosen on an input field to null in Livewire Laravel

Tags: html, laravel, input, rendering, laravel-livewire

I am stuck in an issue. I have a step form in which on each next I check the the data on the livewire component and move to next step but when I go back then the input html tags becomes empty. Attaching the screenshots as well for clear demonstration. I have tried wire:ignore in this input and also in the parent div but did not worked.

[image: image two]

[image: image one]

I have tried JS, wire click, Alpine JS but nothing worked

Comment: Can you share the code of your Component?

Comment: public function setDocumentFiles(): void
    {
        try {
           if (!DocumentsValidator::validate($this)) {
                return;
            }
            $this->pageHeading = __('messages.t_selfie_photo');
            $this->currentStep = 4;
        } catch (ValidationException $e) {
            // Validation error
            throw $e;
        }
    }